# Figures drawn on canvas are oddly cropped

Tags: android, canvas

I'm developing a videogame for android, so I want to have a "manually" canvas drawing oriented style of programming.

so, the onDraw() of my Layout is this:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(0,0,540,1000,Paints.linePaint(Color.BLACK, 1));
        path.drawOn(canvas, 0.5f);
    }
```

where `path.drawOn(Canvas canvas, float opacity);` is a pretty long-to-explain method. `path` contains some segments, and the drawOn draws them on the `canvas`, with the specified `opacity`. Well, that method works as I want:

(Don't care about the black hole and the red thing)

```
opacity  0.0f -> http://i.imgur.com/jbadTyF.png
opacity  0.5f -> http://i.imgur.com/NfRS3at.png
opacity  1.0f -> http://i.imgur.com/3ZL4FcU.png
```

The canvas drawing begins act oddly when I want a smoothly animation that, in this case, is from opacity 0 to 1. I do like this:

```
 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawRect(0,0,540,1000,Paints.linePaint(Color.BLACK, 1));
            path.drawOn(canvas, pathOpacity());
        }

 private float pathOpacity(){
        float tme = (float) getTimeElapsed();
        float bgn = 500;
        float end = 3000;

        if (tme > bgn && tme < end) { return (tme-bgn)/(end-bgn);}
        return tme < bgn ? 0 : 1;
    }

private long bgnTime = -1;

public long getTimeElapsed(){
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - bgnTime;
}

public void setTimeElapsed(long ms){
    bgnTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - ms;
}
```

So, when I call setTimeElapsed(0) the animation starts: it goes from opacity 0 to 1 after 500 ms and stopping at 3000 ms.

*The animation* works: the problem is that the image is oddly cropped like this!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub5OH.png

This happens with all kind of time-related operations, even if I wanna change sizes, or color with the method of "setElapsedTime" it crops. What could this be?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm gonna be honest with you, I don't know what is causing your issue, however if it as you say originates from setTimeElapsed and getTimeElapsed, there is a much much easier way of doing timed events which uses the android CountDownTimer 
here is an example

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 500) {
       @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        }
    }.start();
```

what this code basically does is over 3 seconds (3000 ms) it will call onTick function every 500ms, and exactly after 3000 ms are over it will call the onFinish function.